# How do i force logout from all sessions where i logged in with Github?

Tags: github, github-for-windows

I **need** to force the logout from all the devices and sessions linked to my Github account, the list includes, but is not limited to:

1. VS Code
2. Visual Studio
3. Github Desktop
4. Portainer
5. Jira
6. others

When I take a look at the session list here: https://github.com/settings/security it only shows my current device and not all the services that I listed above.

I already changed the password (that is the login method of all the items in the list) but I've not been logged out from **any** of the above.

FYI: The account is not *Enterprise* level

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the way:
I just went here https://github.com/settings/applications and then hit 'Revoke all' under *Authorized OAuth Apps* (I did not have anything else under the other 2 tabs but maybe you do).

Here is an example of what you would possibly find:

[image]

Hope this helps,
have a good day y'all